# Uploading files with plotly-dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm making an app with plotly-dash to view *.mdf files (Python Library asammdf for loading the files). I made an Upload component (https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/upload) to load the files. I thought of taking the full filename to pass this to the MDF function in the asammdf library to load the file and put data in a graph. However the dash Upload component only returns the filename and not the complete path so I cannot use the MDF function on this. The Upload component also outputs the content of the file as a binary string but not sure how I can pass this to the MDF function.

Somebody knows a way forward for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found out it is possible to work with the contents variable. The MDF function (as well as most read in functions I assume) check if the input is a 'file like' object or a string. If it is a 'file like' object, it directly reads from this object. The contents can be transformed as follows:

```
content_type, content_string = contents[0].split(',')
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
file_like_object = io.BytesIO(decoded)
```